# Div with null size and centered overflowing content: not centered in IE11

Tags: css

My application displays a few small div elements located at absolute positions and connected with straight lines. In order to easily find the center of the div elements, I give them these attributes:

- A null size: `width: 0px; height: 0px;`
- A flex display type with content centered horizontally and vertically
- The content is made visible with `overflow: visible;`

In Chrome and Firefox, this works well. The divs are small dots centered on the position of the element, with a text symbol centered in the div. In Internet Explorer 11 however, the text content is not centered horizontally. Is there a way to make it work while keeping the size null?

The following code snippet shows the problem. In Chrome and Firefox, the text in the green div is centered but not in Internet Explorer. The same code is also shown in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/qLoeq4h8/).

```css
div#layout
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

div#container
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
}

div#content
{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that flexbox only has [**partial support**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in IE11. You may need to use something else if you want IE11 support.

Comment: @Rob - Thanks a lot for the link! Setting `flex-basis` and `text-align: center` for the `content` div allows to center the text in IE.